# args.length and command line arguments

Tags: java, args

I got confused with how to use `args.length`, I have coded something here:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = new int[args.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(a[i]);
    }
}
```

The printout is `0` no matter what value I put in command line arguments, I think I probably confused `args.length` with the `args[0]`, could someone explain? Thank you.

Answer (score 20):

`int` array is initialized to zero (all members will be zero) by default, see [4.12.5. Initial Values of Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5):

> Each class variable, instance variable, or array component is initialized with a default value when      it is created
>   ...
>
> **For type int, the default value is zero**.

You're printing the value of the array, hence you're getting `0`.

Did you try to do this?

```
for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
     System.out.print(args[i]);
}
```

---

`args` contains the *command line* arguments that are passed to the program. 
`args.length` is the length of the arguments. For example if you run:

```
java myJavaProgram first second
```

`args.length` will be 2 and it'll contain `["first", "second"]`.

And the length of the array args is automatically set to 2 (number of your parameters), so there is no need to set the length of args.

Comment: so what does the args mean in"args.length"? is it just a random name of an array or arguments for the lenght?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're missing a code that converts Strings to ints:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] a = new int[args.length];

    // Parse int[] from String[]
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
        a[i] = Interger.parseInt(args[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
        System.out.print(a[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: what if *arg[n]* is not a number? Can you try-catch it?

Comment: @Fernando yes - it will throw a `NumberFormatException` (a `RuntimeException`) if the string does not contain a parsable integer

Answer (score 1):

`args[0]` is the first element of the `args` array. 
`args.length` is the length of the array

Answer (score 1):

The `a` array you iterate on is not the `args` that contains the actual arguments. You should try:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(args[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: so what does the args mean in"args.length"? is it just a random name of an array or arguments for the lenght?

Comment: It is the name for the main method parameter.

Answer (score 1):

```
args.length == 0;
```

if you're looking for this output:

```
args[0]:zero
args[1]:one
args[2]:two
args[3]:three
```

here is the example:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // array with the array name "arg"
    String[] arg = {"zero", "one", "two", "three"};

    for (int i = 0; i < arg.length; ++i) {
        System.out.println("args[" + i + "]:" + arg[i]);
    }
}
```

you have to give a length to the array.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question but I'm also not sure I understand what you're suggesting, could you clarify? Also, format all the code as code.

Answer (score 0):

The arguements you are passing are stored in `args` array and not in your so called array `a`.
By default a properly declared array if not initialized takes the default values of its datatypes. In your case 0.

So you can do:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(args[i]);
    }
}
```

or initialize the array `a` with the `args`.